# When I tried to install WAMP, that popped up the following alert,

Tags: wamp

I clicked OK, it continued to install WAMP.  What exactly is the VCRUNTIME140.dll file? How do I obtain it and fix this error?

[image]

Comment: It is best to install [all these MSVC runtimes](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install required run time required packages to make wamp work on your machine.
Uninstall the current WAMP then install the below package

Try installing Visual C++ Redistributable from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Install WAMP again and it should work.